# Pandas - How to merge two dataframes properly with conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, and I want to merge them based on an `im_id`. However, for the `im_df` I want to keep everything that `dd_df` doesn't have and add what `dd_df` has that `im_df` doesn't have.

Basically, if `im_df` had 1, 2, 3, and 6, and `dd_df` had 1, 2, and 5, I want the total to be 1, 2, 3, 5, and 6 - with 1 and 2 taken from `im_df` (should be the same as what's in `dd_df`).

I've tried this so far:

```
df = im_df.merge(dd_df, on=["im_id"], suffixes=("", "_DROP"))
df = df.filter(regex="^(?!.*_DROP)")

df = df.drop(
    columns=[
        "some_col_from_im_df_we_dont_need",
        "and_another",
    ]
)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset="im_id")
```

This doesn't seem to work, as `df` ends up with about 560k rows. `im_df` initially has 1.5m rows, and `dd_df` has about 570k.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

For instance, one dataframe (x) has the following:

```
f_id | im_id | re_id | ip_id
  1      1       3       4
  2      5       1       3
```

and the other dataframe (y) has

```
f_id | im_id | evo
  1      1      "hello"
  2      5      "yo"
  3      4      "boo"
```

And I want the resultant table to be

```
f_id | im_id | re_id | ip_id | evo
  1       1      3       4     "hello"
  2       5      1       3     "yo"
```

Comment: Try `df = im_df.merge(dd_df, on=["im_id"], suffixes=("", "_DROP"), how="outer")`

Comment: don't believe that works. Some columns have `N/A` now....

Comment: Hmm. Well, it's very hard to figure out how to help you since we don't have the data at hand. Can you send a few sample rows from the two dataframes? And a sample df based on those rows that you want to achieve?

Comment: Sure let me do that :)

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Your example is different from your description above. From the description I understood that you wanted to keep all the rows from both dfs.

Comment: No, maybe my description wasn't the best. I want to "append" non-duplicate rows to the first dataframe from the second, and for the non-duplicates, to also include the columns on the second dataframe onto the first if that makes sense?

Comment: Try getting rid of the `on=["im_id"]` part. A simple `df1.merge(df2)` for me produced the expected out.

Comment: hmm we end up with duplicates if we remove the `on=["im_id"]`. When we include the `on` `f_id` ends up being `<NA>` for some entries. Should we do an `on=["f_id", "im_id"]`? Perhaps we need to `on` whatever columns are the same in the x dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should merge on f_id and im_id and use the `left` attribute:

```
pd.merge(x, y, on=["f_id", "im_id"], how="left")
```

With this you can replicate your example output

```
  f_id im_id re_id  ip_id       evo
0    1     1     3      4   "hello"
1    2     5     1      3      "yo"
```

Comment: what i might have just figured out in the comments above...i wonder what the difference between `left` and `outer` actually is :\

Comment: left returns you all the rows from the first df specified in the merge command, here: x. Outer on the other hand will make you have the rows from both dfs in the end from x and y.

Comment: I see, but we want `evo` to be included in the example I gave in the question. Will this be the case?

Comment: Run the code and find out :)

Comment: hmmm i believe it has worked :D! But i'm confused...  if left returns all from the first df, and we are using left, then why do we get the columns from y that x doesn't have? That's a good thing btw because that's what i want but how does that work :eyes:?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a merge and append. If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want to add new rows from dd_df when they do not exist in im_df. Assuming both dataframes have the same columns (if they do not have the same columns, perform the following on a subset of dd_df that has the same columns, unless you want the new columns added)

```
df_temp = im_df.merge(dd_df, how='inner', on='im_id')
df_new = im_df.append(dd_df[~dd_df.index.isin(df_temp)])
```

This appends all the rows in dd_df that are not in im_df.

You can probably get away with not making df_temp too (haven't tested the following but give it a try)

```
df_new = im_df.append(dd_df[~dd_df.im_id.isin(im_df.im_id)])
```

Comment: Cool, as you can see in the example, not all the columns are the same... and i need what dd_df has that im_df doesn't in terms of columns, but the existing columns that are found in both should be used from im_df :)